# How to convert reqParser in flask to faspapi in python?

Tags: python, fastapi

I am doing migration from flask to fastapi in python and I'm having a problem to convert
this peace of code into fastapi

```
from flask_restx import Resource, Api, fields, reqparse
//some code to generate uuid and add it to the request after login
reqParser = reqparse.RequestParser()
reqParser.add_argument('sid', help='session id', required=True)
```

Their is any way to convert it into fastapi?
I tied to search in their doc but found none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the request object which contains all the information about your incoming request.

```py
from fastapi import Request


@app.get("/dummy")
async def dummy(request: Request):
     print(request.__dict__)
```

Comment: thanks for the help @Yagiz Degirmenci
But I want to add to the request uuid like the about but in fastapi
sry but i dont underston your answer

Comment: Do you want to add UUID to your response header?

Comment: Yes , this is what i want to do